# NSURLErrorDomain on connection loss

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

I often use the app with poor 3G, and generally it falls back wonderfully, with user-friendly 'connection lost' error messages.

The only exception I've come across is when attempting to add an image to a post with no active connection, in which case the below error message is given, rather than a user friendly 'no connection'. Given this seems to be the only feature lacking such a message, I wondered if I had just been missed out.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: That's annoying. Normally we perform requests with NSURLConnection.  For this request, we're using the newer NSURLSessionUploadTask API.  Both fail with the same error code `NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet` but the upload API doesn't appear to set the localized description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next release.  Image uploading now goes through the same channels as everything else, so you should see the same friendly error message with the same "Retry" button.